# Try to retrieve data from XML API link via fetch api and get a parser error

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, fetch

This is the code:

```js
fetch(url,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    },
  }
)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.text();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
    console.log(xml);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

This is how it looks like on the browser:
[image: In the browser]
This is the result in the console:
[image: result]

Comment: `return response.text();`

Comment: The same problem

Comment: @mcorcias Can you link to a reproduction? What do you see when you do `console.log(data)` in your second `then()`?

Comment: I see in the console an empty HTML doc